# Color output in the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, colors

Is there a way to customize ubuntu terminal in such a way that output of the any command is colorized according to some patterns. In .bashrc I can customize prompt, but I am looking for something similar to what MobaXTerm does on windows: when I cat file and there is some specific word, like false, error or failure it is colored red. Words: success, true are colored green. It really helps reading logs, configurations etc. Is there a way to achieve this in terminal?

Comment: Do You have some specific tool in mind ? I think most of the linux tools have some option to enable colored output. If not You can use alternate tool. Instead of `cat` You can use `bat`, instead of `ls` You can use `exa` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You could use colorizer tools, see e.g. https://superuser.com/q/602294.

I'm not aware of any terminal emulator for Linux that offers such coloring (syntax highlighting) on its own. If there exists one, someone will sure correct me.

There's a [proof of concept patch for VTE](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788673#c9) with hardwired words, you can modify them or add new ones by changing the source. [VTE](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte) is used by several terminal emulators, including e.g. GNOME Terminal, Tilix or Xfce Terminal; thus if you patch, compile and install VTE, you can use this feature in any of these.